# Modularize javascript code SONAR duplicate block

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, sonarqube

I have the below block of code which SONAR recognizes as duplicate. Can someone please tell me how to correct this.

```
import fields from '../../utils/utils';

 dispatch(
   fields.change([
     {
       id: 'userData',
       value: customer.eduSavings === null || customer.eduSavings.total === null ? ''
         : customer.edusavings.toString()
    },
    {
       id: 'emoloyeeData',
       value: customer.workSavings === null || customer.workSavings.total === null ? ''
         : customer.workSavings.toString()
    }
  ])
)
```

Sonar says that the null check and toString() applied on `value` field is duplicated. How can i loop through and apply fields.change to respective ids.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `customer.workSavings` is an object and `customer.workSavings.total` is an property of `customer.workSavings.total`? If that is true, then in the case that `customer.workSavings` is null, of course `customer.workSavings.total` is also null, SONAR is detecting that you checked the same logic and showed a duplicate.

```
import fields from '../../utils/utils';

 dispatch(
   fields.change([
     {
       id: 'userData',
       value: customer.eduSavings === null ? 
         : customer.edusavings.toString()
    },
    {
       id: 'emoloyeeData',
       value: customer.workSavings === null ? 
         : customer.workSavings.toString()
    }
  ])
)
```

You don't need to check if `customer.workSavings.total` is null if `customer.workSavings` is null already

Comment: there is a case where customer.workSavings can be null or customer.workSavings.total can be null. how do i validate if both are not null ?

Answer (score 0):

When SonarQube reports a duplication, it's saying that the block in question is an exact duplicate of a block in the same file or another file.  The question and answer about the logic of this block is irrelevant.

Typically, the left margin will show a vertical blue line indicating that the block is a duplicate of another block.  If you click on that vertical blue line, it will tell you where the other duplicated block is.